# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more variables have some issues with their values in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins declarative pipeline wherein I am trying to store the value returned from a method into environment variable as shown below.

```
steps {
                
                script {
                    
                    def job = getJob(JOB_NAME)
                    def param = getParam(job, "Ser")
                    echo param.getValue()
                }
                
                
            }
            environment {
                p_values = param.getValue()
            }
```

But while running above script I am getting below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more variables have some issues with their values: p_values
```

Could you please assist me here to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `environment` block will be executed prior to the `script` block.

You can try assign value to an new environment variable within `script` block,  rather then in `environment` block as following:

```
script {          
  def job = getJob(JOB_NAME)
  def param = getParam(job, "Ser")
  echo param.getValue()
  env.p_values = param.getValue()
}
```